# Angular can't navigate to other component

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular.

I'm trying to build a simple application with a list page and a detail page.

The issues are multiple:

1- the search page shows the the th twice and shows it in all pages.

2- when I try to use route link, the app doesn't load the detail page.

I've spent hour searching solution in order to fix this issues...

Here my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SearchService } from './home/search.service';
import { SearchComponent } from './home/search.component';
import { CharDetailComponent } from './char-detail/char-detail.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    CharDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  providers: [SearchService],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }

export class MyTemplatesModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchComponent } from './home/search.component';
import { CharDetailComponent } from './char-detail/char-detail.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: SearchComponent},
  {path:'showDetails', component: CharDetailComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';
import { MovieCharacter } from './movie-character';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit{
  people: MovieCharacter[];
  constructor(private searchService: SearchService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
      console.log('data');
     }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchService.getPeople().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.people = data.results;
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.searchService.getPeople().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.people = data.results;
    });
  }

  onSelect(name: string){
    this.router.navigate(['/showDetails/'+name]);
  }
}
```

**search.component.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>url</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of people">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.description}}</td>

        <td><a href="{{person.url}}">{{person.url}}</a></td>
        <a href="/showDetails"><button >
            <span>Go to master Page</span>
        </button>
        </a>
    </tr>

</table>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**char-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieCharacter } from '../home/movie-character';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-char-detail',
  templateUrl: './char-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./char-detail.component.css']
})
export class CharDetailComponent implements OnInit{
  people: MovieCharacter[];
  param : string;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.showDetails();
  }

  showDetails(){
    this.param = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');

  }
}
```

**char-detail.component.html**

```
<p>my name is {{param}}</p>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I know the code is very dirty and there are a lot of mistake, but please help me!

Comment: Initially in `{path:'showDetails', component: CharDetailComponent},` if you want to pass parameter name, it should be configured as `{path:'showDetails/:name', component: CharDetailComponent},`

Comment: Also navigation should look like `this.router.navigate(['/showDetails', name]);` instead of `this.router.navigate(['/showDetails/'+name]);`

Comment: l'm not seeing your show details accepting a name parameter. Have you done something like: {path:'showDetails/:name', component: CharDetailComponent}, and also change your html like: <a [routerLink]="['showDetails',person.name]"><button >
            <span>Go to master Page</span>
        </button>
        </a>

Comment: Also, keep in mind if you have nested `<router-outlet>` you'd need to use `children` property of `Route`. In your example you wouldn't need `router-outlet` in char-detail because there are no child routes associated with `/showDetails`, at least based on the route configuration you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Angular!

To begin with, remove the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from all pages except app.component.html.

After you have done this, retest your pages. If the details page still doesn't show, look at your console for any Javascript errors and please post here :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code. Here is the solution:

1. Remove the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from all pages except app.component.html
2. If you need to pass name parameter in showDetails page then you need to specify that in app-routing.module.ts so instead of `{path:'showDetails', component: CharDetailComponent}`, you need to put `{path:'showDetails/:name', component: CharDetailComponent}`

After this change, ng serve your application again and you are good to go :). Hope this help you.